# Resurrection - what is the best strategy?

Tags: ios, temple-run

I'm trying to determine what is the best strategy with regard to resurrection in the game temple run. 
On one hand it is nice to feel protected with this extra life while having the wings. Very often I do need it, so with that respect - it is a good thing. 
On the other hand switching "modes" and going throught periods without wings gets me unconsetrated: I'm looking at the scoreboard, I'm trying to double click, I loose focus and I slip. 
Also, I've a feeling that after I'm resurrected, my character runs a little bit slower. My current strategy is running with the wings for about 20 second, and then purposely jump off the cliff. This way I'm both protected for 20 second, and After resurrection game slows down. 
I wonder what is your strategy (especially if you are > 10M). Do you bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experimented with the same strategy. I've found that often, it is too distracting for me to use the wings, but if I wait until an opportunity arises where I can use them without endangering my life, I usually use them. Instead of purposefully jumping off, I usually use them when I can tell I'm getting into an especially difficult area, which seem to happen around certain milestones (it seems to me that the difficulty often ebbs and flows).